# Modal Window Submission has Issue Gathering $_GET variables

Tags: php, email, variables, get

I'm trying to send the values of several `$_GET` variables with my email that my php script is sending.

These variables look like:

```
$path=$_GET['path'];
$education=$_GET['edu'];
$cert=$_GET['cert'];
$server_prefix = 'https://';
$server_address = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

I'm trying to send all as part of the `$message` variable in my email.

I've done a test against them and the following variables properly send in email:

```
$server_prefix
$server_address
```

The following do not work:

```
$path=$_GET['path'];
$education=$_GET['edu'];
$cert=$_GET['cert'];
```

I'm doing this by assigning the variables to `$message` like:

```
$message = $server_address;
```

The url looks like: `someaddress.com/pathway?path=3&edu=4&cert=#`

The modal window and url look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHXn1.png  (someone please edit and add this to the post as I lost my old account (and all the rep) -thanks )

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You know that a modal has nothing to do with getting a `$_GET` value

Comment: Modal window - http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/# . Not a mod**e**l

Comment: modal and modal window are the same

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question was using $_SESSION variables in Php to pass variable(s) from one page to another page.

When utilizing ajax through jquery, $_SESSION variables are a viable option.